# Find items from json array using NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js

Am trying to search for particular items from a JSON array and return the items...

```
 result = {
      FF: {
        server: 'deskes.com',
        result: 'succes'
    
      },
         {
        server: 'cleantarge.com',
        result: 'Failed'
    
      },
         {
        server: 'fance34.com',
        result: 'success'
    
      },{
        server: 'deskes.com',
        result: 'Failed'
    
      },
    
    }
```

I have following JSON data.
I want to search items based on server

I used the code

```
var arrFound = result.filter(function(item) {
    return item.server == 'deskes.com';
});

But getting TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'filter'
```

my resulting JSON after searching the data will be:

```
result = {
  FF: {
    server: 'deskes.com',
    result: 'succes'

  },

  {
    server: 'deskes.com',
    result: 'Failed'

  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filter` method is only available on arrays, and it looks like you're calling it on an object (from the outer bracket). You can work around this by looping through the keys:

```
var arrFound = Object.keys(result).filter(function(key) {
    return result[key].server == 'deskes.com';
// to cast back from an array of keys to the object, with just the passing ones
}).reduce(function(obj, key){
    obj[key] = result[key];
    return obj;
}, {});;
```

Answer (score 6):

You also can use the  **arrow function** version of ECMAScript 2015:

```
rta =  result.filter(it => it.server === 'deskes.com');
```

The code:

```js
var result = [
  {
   server: 'deskes.com',
    result: 'succes'

  },
     {
    server: 'cleantarge.com',
    result: 'Failed'

  },
     {
    server: 'fance34.com',
    result: 'success'

  },{
    server: 'deskes.com',
    result: 'Failed'

  }
];



var rta =  result.filter(it => it.server === 'deskes.com');

console.log(rta);

/*
Result:

[
  {
    "server": "deskes.com",
    "result": "succes"
  },
  {
    "server": "deskes.com",
    "result": "Failed"
  }
]

*/
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is with your json, it needs to be an array.

Here is a code sample I have tested and it works fine.

```
var result = [
  {
   server: 'deskes.com',
    result: 'succes'

  },
     {
    server: 'cleantarge.com',
    result: 'Failed'

  },
     {
    server: 'fance34.com',
    result: 'success'

  },{
    server: 'deskes.com',
    result: 'Failed'

  }
];

var arrFound = result.filter(function(item) {
  return item.server == 'deskes.com';
});

console.log(arrFound);

// Outputs: [ { server: 'deskes.com', result: 'succes' }, { server: 'deskes.com', result: 'Failed' } ]
```